# JSON parser nested array value

Tags: json

```
{
    "Head1" : {
        "roll no" : 2323,
        "person name" : "Ankit",
        "person mark" : 1124,
        "person average" : 92.34657163223787
    },
    "Head2" : {
        "subject1" : 135,
        "subject2" : 184,
        "subject3" : 200,
        "subject4" : 200,
        "subject5" : 200,
        "subject6" : 180
    },
    "Head3" : ["{\"mobile\":\"919958254506\",\"profile\":[\"{\\\"profile_TYPE\\\":\\\"PERSONAL\\\",{ \\\"number\\\":\\\"919958254506\\\"} }\",\"{\\\"profile_TYPE\\\":\\\"PERSONAL\\\",{ \\\"number\\\":\\\"919958254506\\\"} }\",\"{\\\"profile_TYPE\\\":\\\"PERSONAL\\\",{ \\\"number\\\":\\\"919958254506\\\"} }\"],\"SMS_DATE\":\"9/15/2015 10:59:59\",\"SMS_DATASOURCE\":\"Hi Ankit. How r u .\"}"]
}
```

The above is my json i want to display particular value for example head3 value of profile value of profile type and number . how can i parse these value thanks advance..

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: By the way, your JSON is very inconvenient to work with. Why do you serialize objects within objects? Is this JSON generated by you?

Comment: here i am using javascript and jquery. This has been generated by Moongo DB .